# Category order in bidirectional bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a simple bar plot of categories mapped to positive and negative values.  I understand that category order is set via factor in ggplot2 however, the categories are only in order for values below zero and out of order for values above. I can't manage to get the categories in the correct order in both the plot and the legend.

Consider the following data and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dat <- tribble(
  ~val, ~cat, ~label, ~order,
  -10, "Negative 2", "A", 1,
  -20, "Negative 1", "A", 2,
  5, "Positive 1", "A", 3,
  10, "Positive 2", "A", 4,
  20, "Positive 3", "A", 5
) |>
  mutate(cat = factor(cat, levels = unique(cat)))

dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = val, 
             y = label, 
             fill = cat)) +
  geom_col(color = "transparent") +
  geom_label(aes(label = order), 
             show.legend = FALSE, 
             color = "white", 
             size = 5, 
             position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Here the legend is in the correct order, but the positive categories in the plot are reversed. The order should be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` not `1, 2, 5, 4, 3`. How can I fix it so both the categories and legend are in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `ggplot2` takes the order of your factor into account. However, by default `position_stack` will

> automatically stack values in reverse order of the group aesthetic, which for bar charts is usually defined by the fill aesthetic. (See `?position_stack`)

Hence, the in your case the order is 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1. And that's what the stack is showing.

With a diverging bar chart and both positive and negative values getting the order of the stack and in the legend right is more tricky and I would suggest to explicitly set the `group` aes, i.e. in your case you could set the order of the stack by recording according to the `val`ue which is what your order reflects but stick with your order for the `fill`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dat <- tribble(
  ~val, ~cat, ~label, ~order,
  -10, "Negative 2", "A", 1,
  -20, "Negative 1", "A", 2,
  5, "Positive 1", "A", 3,
  10, "Positive 2", "A", 4,
  20, "Positive 3", "A", 5
) |>
  mutate(
    order1 = reorder(cat, -val),
    cat = factor(cat, unique(cat))
  )

dat |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = val,
    y = label,
    fill = cat,
    group = order1
  )) +
  geom_col(color = "transparent") +
  geom_label(aes(label = order),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    color = "white",
    size = 5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan.  The grouping was the puzzle piece I was missing.